# Rewrited url for page just points to index

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

The problem I am facing is as follow:

I created a new page in Wordpress with a url rewrite '/foo/'. Probably I hit something
(just configured things in the Admin panel not in the database!) an now /foo/ just points to my index and doesn't point to the given page (anymore!). If I just change '/foo/' to something like this '/foo-1/' it works perfectly.

I think it's to hard figure it out what goes wrong but maybe someone has a good suggestion or knows which data I need to remove from the database!

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Comment: have you tried [flush_rewrite_rules();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) ??

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Make a answer of your comment and I will accept :)

Comment: Just posted an answer and comment to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you are fiddling with URL rewrites ( especially with new custom_post_types and taxonomies, but basically everywhere ) it is very important not to forget [`flush_rewrite_rules();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) which basically take care of flushing the WP rewrite rules ( like it's name ) - thus allowing you to declare new ones without a conflict.